# Tuple Must Contain at least two elements

Tags: c#, .net

Going through the Microsoft Documentation and Working through the tutorials, I'm currently working on the Classes and Objects Module.

```
using System;

namespace classes
{
public class BankAccount
{
    public string Number { get; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; }
    public BankAccount(string name, decimal initialBalance)
    {
      this.Owner = name;
      this.Balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public void MakeDeposit(decimal amount, DateTime date, string note)
    {
    }

    public void MakeWithdrawal(decimal amount, DateTime date, string note)
    {
    }
}
```

}

is what we start with, and I'm to call upon this class as a test in the Program.cs file

```
using System;

namespace classes
{
    public class Program
    {
        var account = new BankAccount("<HAMID>", 1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Account {account.Number} was created for {account.Owner} with {account.Balance} initial balance.");

    }
}
```

but i get this error in the Console.WriteLine("...")

```
"Type expected , tuple must be at least two elements, ) expected, invalid token $"Account {account.Number} was created for {account.Owner} with {account.Balance} initial balance."
```

The link to the article i'm going by is

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/introduction-to-classes

appreciate any insight on my dilemma.

Comment: `Going through the Microsoft Documentation` +1!

Comment: Where is Main function in Program class? :)

Comment: @Johnny Irreleveant. The issue is that the code is not in a method

Comment: .NET core is the framework, they said it was multi platform so I figured I would use that.

Comment: @hamdoe if you use .NET 6 and later, you can directly write `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` no need any boilerplate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing the `static void Main(string[] args)` method in your `Program` class.

Example:

```
using System;

namespace classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: more specifically, executing code cannot be directly part of a class

Answer (score -1):

In my case this was a very interesting error that was only happening @ Azure Build Pipeline... the error was this one indicated by the yellow arrow:

[image]

I created a class and added `()` to its name by mistake... pretty interesting one indeed! :D